# Comparing Values in Individual Rows to Corresponding Rows In Different Column

Tags: r, match, rows

I'm new to the forum and relatively new to R.

I'm currently manipulating my data. The data are placed in a DataFrame. I'd like to compare the values in each row of column 'Prime' to each corresponding row of column 'target'. If the values match I want to add the value '1' to the corresponding row in column 'Match' and if they don't match add a '0'.

Below is an example of the columns and the solution under column 'Match'

```
Prime    Target  Match
faces0   faces0   1 
faces0   faces0   1 
houses1  faces0   0
```

I toyed around using `ifelse` and `identical` but it compares the objects as a whole and not the individual and corresponding rows.

Can anyone suggest a means of comparing Prime and Target while assigning a value to Match dependant on a match being made or not?

Thanks very much for your time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a straight logical test, so if you compare the two columns for equality, you will get `TRUE`/`FALSE`, which can easily be converted to `1`/`0` with `as.numeric()`. Depending on how your columns are coded, they may need to be converted to character before the comparison:

```
dat$Match <- as.numeric(dat$Prime == dat$Target)
dat$Match
# [1] 1 1 0
```

Comment: That's a beautiful and elegant solution.

It worked a treat.

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `ifelse` or `match`but need to convert to numeric before that. Here is the solution.

```
mydata<-structure(list(Prime = structure(c(1L, 1L, 2L), .Label = c("faces0", 
"houses1"), class = "factor"), Target = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L
), .Label = "faces0", class = "factor"), Match = c(1, 1, 0)), .Names = c("Prime", 
"Target", "Match"), row.names = c(NA, -3L), class = "data.frame")

> mydata$Match<-with(mydata,ifelse(as.numeric(Prime)==as.numeric(Target),1,0))
> mydata
    Prime Target Match
1  faces0 faces0     1
2  faces0 faces0     1
3 houses1 faces0     0

mydata$Match<-with(mydata,match(as.numeric(Prime),as.numeric(Target),nomatch=0))
 > mydata
        Prime Target Match
    1  faces0 faces0     1
    2  faces0 faces0     1
    3 houses1 faces0     0
```